# Apache running on XAMPP, but localhost is not reachable

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I installed XAMPP and started the Apache Server and MySQL. However, if I try to access https://localhost/, it just shows a blank page in Firefox. I am on a Windows 10 machine. I already tried to change the localhost port from 80 to 8080, but it says that it cannot open the page this way.
Any ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: _it says that it cannot open the page this way_ What does it exactley say?

Comment: try http://localhost/ instead of https. You will not have a ssl certificate and thus the browser blocks it.

If that is not the case, please show us your index.html/index.php content

Comment: It says "403 Forbidden" if I put http://localhost/.

Comment: the index.php says :"<?php
 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
  $uri = 'https://';
 } else {
  $uri = 'http://';
 }
 $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
 exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
"